# how to display selected value in mysql database in label through vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have a code but it's not working. i was trying to put a value in label2 but it's not working. please help me.

```
Private Sub student_no_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles student_no.Click
    MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; port=3307; user id = root; password = 1234; database = sample;"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MySqlConnection.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = " select id from sample.student where last_name = '" & txtlastname.Text & "' "
        Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConnection)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        Label2.Text = query.ToString

        MessageBox.Show("Student Number Generated")
        MySqlConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConnection.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If READER.Read() Then
    Label2.Text = READER.GetString(0)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using .ToString on query, which is a string. What you should be doing is operations on the READER object.

Since SELECT will always return a list of results, you have to treat the results as such, like...

```
While READER.Read()
  MessageBox.Show((READER.GetInt32(0)))
End While
```

.Read() returns the next element in the returned rowset